# credssp: Server did not response with a CredSSP token after step TLS Handshake - actual 'Negotiate, Kerberos, Basic realm=\"WSMAN\", CredSSP'

Tags: windows, ansible, credssp

Am trying to setup Ansible server with Windows hosts and using CredSSP for authentication purpose.

When setting the inventory file to use http instead of https, I get the below error

credssp: Server did not response with a CredSSP token after step TLS Handshake - actual 'Negotiate, Kerberos, Basic realm="WSMAN", CredSSP

Can anyone please help me on this issue. The basic authentication works fine but CredSSP does not.

Am trying to run a basic ping module to check connectivity of the host using the CredSSP auth

```
\[win\]
host-IP-here

\[win:vars\]
ansible_user=my@domain.com
ansible_password=MyPasswordhere
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_port=5985
ansible_winrm_transport=credssp
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```